# Android webview setting

Tags: android

Someone can show me how to set my own custom font to the whole webview via this sniff.
websetting.setFixFontFamily(string)
I struggle for that for 5 days.But till not show my own font.I also try svg insteant of ttf.Help.Thank for your advance.

Comment: why you dot try to change in the webside itself?

Comment: I am trying to develop web app so.

Comment: so what? set your fonts in the web page itself

Comment: huh...I am not admin of all site.

Comment: Show me sniff, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it worked for me.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {        
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);                
            String font="Georgia, serif";

 String font1="\"Palatino Linotype\", \"Book Antiqua\", Palatino, serif";

//  String font2="\"Times New Roman\", Times, serif";

 //  String font3="\"Courier New\", Courier, monospace";

 //  String font4="\"Lucida Console\", Monaco,monospace";                       
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.style.fontFamily='"+font+"';})()");

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But my font is in assets folder :-)

Comment: @Ayemino i Think u cant load custom fonts into webview there are certain fonts which can used. Thanks.